# Getting different output from setRegion: on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

Here is my question: When I am trying to set the zoom level of my map, I is zooming to a different level than I requested.

Here is the code I am using:

```
        MKCoordinateRegion cRegion =                       
        MKCoordinateRegionMake
        (myMapView.userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(.001, .0001));

        MKCoordinateRegion aRegion = [myMapView regionThatFits:cRegion];
        [myMapView setRegion:cRegion animated:YES];
```

The first thing I do is create a region with the span being .001 in the latitude direction and .0001 in the longitude direction. My reasoning is that this will give me a sliver that spans exactly .001 degrees latitude. Then I can throw it into regionThatFits: and it will spit out a region that spans .001 degrees latitude and whatever my map view needs to span in the longitude direction to keep that aspect ratio. Instead I get:

```
  Lat Range: 0.000969508
  Long Range: 0.000858307
```

Any idea why the Lat Range, which I thought would be .001 isn't?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I found a solution to exactly get the desired map region, see my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612007/mkmapview-setregion-snaps-to-predefined-zoom-levels/7935

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the MKMapView's setRegion. See See [MKMapView show incorrectly saved region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383296/why-mkmapview-region-is-different-than-requested)

Comment: Actually it's not a bug. It is well documented and behave exactly as documented. See https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html