# How to Zoom Map to my annotation placemark - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have one class that has all the MapKit functions and another class where I call the MapKit. My goal is to give an address (String) and the map show a placemark with zoom to that location.

So far I managed to get the map working and the placemark is in the right street, but dont zoom to the placemark location.

Map is declared like:
`@IBOutlet var mapPreview: MKMapView!`

Here is the code of the placemark. How can I zoom to that placemark?

```
    var address = restaurante.rua + " " + restaurante.numero + "," + restaurante.localidade + ", Portugal"
    var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {
            self.mapPreview.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS MKMapView zoom to show all markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434020/ios-mkmapview-zoom-to-show-all-markers)

Comment: Nope. Quote from that question: "to enable zooming etc around one of the points - but that's not what I want...", but this is exactly what I want. :)

Comment: The question has some really interesting answers. Check the function mentioned in the answer below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the function

```
func showAnnotations(_ annotations: [AnyObject]!,
            animated animated: Bool)
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/showAnnotations:animated:)

Comment: Solved by adding your function and this:

self.mapPreview.showAnnotations(self.mapPreview.annotations, animated: true)